# ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded for angular 6 reaactive form

Tags: angular

I have angular reactive form with formarray. When I use valueChanges I get:

> core.js:1624 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
this.addmemberForm.get('FamilyInfo.newchildren').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()) 
      .subscribe(val => {

        const kofi = [val];
        console.log(kofi);
        const ydaw = kofi[0];
        const rad =ydaw[ydaw.length - 1]
        console.log(rad);

        const akwa =ydaw.indexOf(rad);
        console.log(akwa);
        this.index = akwa;

       this.productcount = rad.profession;

       if(this.productcount !==null){
        console.log(this.productcount);
        this.products= this.productcount
        this.item = this.products.stockname;
              (<FormArray>this.addmemberForm.get('FamilyInfo.newchildren')).at(this.index).get("item").patchValue(this.item);
       }

    });
```

Comment: Why are you patching inside subscribe block?